# Errors in Xcode Generated Header File

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm receiving about 15 errors in my Xcode generated header file, only when I'm building to a device. When I build to the simulator everything works perfectly fine.

I've noticed the errors center around Swift classes that intermix Objective-C in them, however, why that wouldn't cause errors when built to a simulator I don't know.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before?

Edit: The errors are all about not being able to find a protocol or interface declaration.

Comment: Are you using cocoapods ? What are those errors ?

Comment: We're using cocoapods, but most of the errors are related to our classes. The errors are all about not being able to find the protocol or interface declaration.

Comment: Post screenshot of errors